# Mapping URL "names" to Controllers in JSPs

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm wondering if there is a way in Spring MVC to map "url names" to URLS.  For instance:

```
list_users -> /admin/users/list
edit_user?id=123 -> /admin/users/edit/123 (or /users/edit?id=123)
list_programs -> /admin/programs/list
```

I come from a PHP background(specifically Symfony), where each URL/action has a "route name", with which you can create URLs in your view templates.  In Symfony, you would do something like this in your template:

```
{{ path('user_edit', { 'id' : 123} }}

//output = /admin/users/edit/123
```

URLs do not necessarily need to be RESTful, but I'm just wondering if something like this could be accomplished with Spring MVC.

**Possible Solution that I've thought about:**

Keeping urls listed in a properties/messages file, like:

```
url.users.edit=/admin/users/edit/{id}
url.users.list=/admin/users/list
```

and then using `<spring:message code="url.users.list" />` or something like this to generate the URLs.  Is this already a generally accepted solution? Is this perhaps bad practice?

*The reason I'm asking, is it seems like bad practice to have full URLs spread out throughout JSPs.  What happens if 25 URLs are under an "/admin" sub-directory, and I want to move them to a different sub-directory, say "/backend".*

Forgive me if there is a duplicate post somewhere on this, or if there is a simple solution that I'm overlooking, but it is a hard topic find a specific answer for.

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend reading this documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html. Its pretty long, but I think it explains really well how to create Controllers with Spring mvc. And you also might want to look at this page to learn how to use the `<c:url>` tag : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm.

Comment: I have a pretty complete understanding(and experience) of how Controllers & Spring MVC works, as well as the JSTL core.  Can you elaborate on how your comment relates to anything in my post?

Comment: I apologize I missed the point of your question. I will be interested to see the answer though. As a side note, the Play framework does this. :)

Comment: @jlars62 - I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this post, I have found a solution for mapping names to URLs for Spring MVC:

https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router

This solution gets the job done quite nicely, and I especially like the fact that all of your URLs / routes are able to be kept in a central location.  This implementation renders the `@RequestMapping` annotation useless.

**Please keep the following in mind:**

Make sure your dispatcher servlet uses `*` as the URL parameter.  Took me awhile to figure out that `/` alone will not work, and will cause URLs to be generated incorrectly.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```